# C#: Split a string (or user input) into individual characters withOUT using an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

Ok here's what im trying to do. The user is prompted to enter an 8 digit number (7 numbers plus a hyphen

781-0432

I want it to break it apart and store it into 8 separate char variables without using an array:

a = 7
b = 8
c = 1
...
h = 2

Ive been trying to do it with the Console.Read() method:

a = Console.Read();
b = Console.Read();
etc

Problem is, i don't know how to key the Console.Read() to stop reading after that. If the module is contained in a loop, it seems to not reset on the next call.

I know what you're thinking. Why the hell would you not use an array or the split to char array option? Well because it is a homework assignment that is very specific on it wants you to accomplish it. This is the first one to stump me in a while. Any insight?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "If the module is contained in a loop, it seems to not reset on the next call."?

Comment: @kirk: Its kind of hard to describe. When you first use Console.Read(), it prompts you for the input. With each subsequent use of the Read() method, it won't prompt you as long as there are still characters left in the original prompt that haven't been read yet; so instead it will just read the next character rather than prompt you again. So if I had some sort of break statement that would throw an error if the 4th position wasn't a hyphen '-', the program would ask me for a new phone number and then go back to trying to validate it, BUT instead of the Read() method starting at the 1st positio

Comment: n, it would start at the 5th position because it wasn't finished with the original entry, regardless of the fact that it now has a new entry. its really messy

Answer (score 3):

It already is an Array (well, sort of*)!

You can access each individual character by using an indexer on the string. For example:

```
string str = "781-0432"; // To take input, you can use Console.ReadLine()
char firstChar = str[0];
char secondChar = str[1];
// etc
```

*Technically a `string` is not an array, but it has a custom indexer that lets it be used like a `char[]`.

Comment: i decided to go with this one thanks! It worked out. The finished product the most convoluted piece of garbage ever, but it follows the guidelines so im content :)

Comment: @Sinaesthetic if you liked this answer you should mark your question as answered by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
public char ReadChar()
{
   char r = ' ';
   while (r < '0' || r > '9')
      r = Console.ReadKey();
   return r;
}

a = ReadChar();
b = ReadChar();
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

what about storing your characters in a POCO that you can retrieve later?

```
public void SomeEvent()
{
    string PhoneNumber = "781-0432"
    Alphabet alphabet = SplitNumber(PhoneNumber);
    // Pass the alphabet object around and maintain the individual characters!
}

public Alphabet SplitNumber(string number)
{
    Alphabet alphabet = new Alphabet();
    alphabet.a = number[0];
    alphabet.b = number[1];
    alphabet.c = number[2];
    alphabet.d = number[3];
    alphabet.e = number[4];
    alphabet.f = number[5];
    alphabet.g = number[6];
    alphabet.h = number[7];
    return alphabet;
}

class Alphabet
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public string c;
    public string d;
    public string e;
    public string f;
    public string g;
    public string h;
}
```

Now you can move `Alphabet` around your app and maintain the individual characters.

Comment: I used the telerik converter to convert from VB.  Sorry if it's a little off.

Comment: if it's always those 8 characters, then this works just fine.  I'm more concerned about the ability to just save it as a Class Object that can be used later.

Comment: Also, I just use "Alphabet" because your question stated that you were storing it as a,b,c etc